# decoding DHCP Giaddr, Yiaddr, Ciaddr, siaddr fields with dpkt - python issue

Tags: python-2.7, dpkt

Whenever I try to load Giaddr (or YIADDR Ciaddr, siaddr ) for any DHCP packet it **prints random string of numbers**. ( this happens for each n every packet I load)

Am I doing something wrong or it's a bug in code?

code

```
dh = dpkt.dhcp.DHCP(udp.data)
print dh.giaddr
```

**output : 
182435815**

I am pretty sure that my **giaddr(relay ip)** is 10.223.191.231 - confirmed in wireshark for this packet.

Answer (score 1):

Your output is correct. You have a the integer value of the address.
To print the dotted-decimal version, you can do this:

```
>>> import struct
>>> socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack(">L",x))
'10.223.191.231'
```

Comment: @Manojcode if that worked for you, can you please mark it as the answer